# Desk.com OAuth problems in php

Tags: php, oauth, salesforce

I'm trying to connect to our CRM platform using this code:

https://gist.github.com/2564090

But it is failing outright at line 28:

$oauth = new OAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

Is there something I need to do to instantiate a new OAuth object? Am I supposed to be referring to some library or an include file? Or do I have to enable something in my php.ini config file? Why won't 'new OAuth()' work for me? All I ever get is: 500 - Internal server error.

Comment: did you follow the instructions at the top of the file? are you using PHP 5.4 with OAuth Extension installed?

Comment: Using php v5.3.10. Is oauth not pre-installed?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Paul, you need to install the PECL extension https://www.php.net/oauth

Once you have your extension installed you can create a method like the one I wrote to connect to the API.
As you can see I defined a private method that is stored in a Client class that I named Desk_Client.
If you need to perform multiple requests it might be better to move the oAuth object creation in the class constructor and store it into an instance variable.

```
const API_URL = "https://YOURSITE.desk.com/api/v2/"; 

// Access token & secret (Click [Your Access Token] on App Listing) 
// https://[yoursite].desk.com/admin/settings/api-applications)
const ACCESS_TOKEN = "*****";
const ACCESS_SECRET = "*****";

// Application key and secret found here: 
// https://[yoursite].desk.com/admin/settings/api-applications
const CONSUMER_KEY = "*****";
const CONSUMER_SECRET = "*****";

/**
 * Utility method to perform a request to the Desk.com API.
 *
 * @param string $actionPath - The relative path to an API action (e.g. companies)
 * @param array $params - Array containing key value parameters for the request
 * @param string $request - POST, GET, PUT, PATCH
 * @return Array
 */
private function _performRequest($actionPath, $params = null, $request = OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET) {

    $url = self::API_URL.$actionPath;

    try {
        $oauth = new OAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        $oauth->setToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
        $oauth->disableSSLChecks();
        
        switch ($request) {
            case OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET:
                // Add get params to the url.
                $url .= ($params && $request === "GET") ? "?".http_build_query($params) : "";
                $oauth->fetch($url);
                break;

            case OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST:
                $oauth->fetch($url, json_encode($params), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
                break;

            default:
                $oauth->fetch($url, json_encode($params), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_PUT);
        }
        $result = $oauth->getLastResponse();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        error_log("Error: ".$e->getCode()." - ".$e->getMessage());
    }

    return json_decode($result);
}
```

I'm sharing this code since the desk.com Api documentation provides just a sample Ruby snippet and I hope that this code will save someone some time

Answer (score 0):

You need to install OAuth from pecl for instance